# Two HTTP interceptors implemented but only one is called

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-module

I've two modules, each one with its own interceptor:

a.module.ts

```
//AInterceptor
@Injectable()
export class AInterceptors implements HttpInterceptor {...}

//a.module
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,        
        HttpClientModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AInterceptors,
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    exports: []
})
```

b.module.ts

```
//BInterceptor
@Injectable()
export class BInterceptors implements HttpInterceptor {...}

//b.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: BInterceptors,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
```

I import them in my app.module:

```
//app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    AModule,
    BModule,
BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

If both imported, AInterceptor works (intercepts the request), BInteceptor no.
I tested them separately and they work fine. What am I missing?

UPDATE: for some reason, if I invert the import order in the app.module, they work both.

Comment: This could be one reason https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor#usage-notes

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear point to provide them in separate modules, because if you will use lazy loading, it will simply don't work because HTTPClientModule is already started when you try to set the interceptor. Here is longread about this: https://dev.to/devakone/angular-when-httpinterceptor-doesn-t-work-with-lazy-loaded-modules-3ipg